# How to get the length of the array if data is push into the array in the string and number format inAngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]I am using `Object.keys` function for get the `length` of the array but after push the data in array it will be show array `length` is undefine [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAijz.png).

so tell me sir how to fix this ?

```js
$scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList       = []; 
$scope.countBuyerInAlbum          = 0;
$scope.totalSharedUserCount       = [];
$scope.selectBuyerInAlbum = function(index, isChecked, keyId) {
if(isChecked) {
  if($scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList.indexOf(keyId)){
      var keyId = keyId;
      var buyerKeyId = keyId.toString();
      $scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList[buyerKeyId] = keyId;
      $scope.countBuyerInAlbum ++;

      $scope.totalSharedUserCount = Object.keys($scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList).length;
    }
} else {
    var index  = keyId;
    delete $scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList[index];
    $scope.countBuyerInAlbum --;
    $scope.totalSharedUserCount = Object.keys($scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList).length;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why use `Object.key` ? you don't need use that to know length

Comment: sir i am also using length but after push the data length will be undefined?

Comment: You should use `$scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList.push(keyId);` to `push` data to array and use `$scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList.length`

Comment: sir i am not change the format of the push the data?

Comment: I think you are storing key-value pair, which should be done in object. If `buyerKeyId` is numeric then you will get sparse array and have to go through each element and check for its value to calculate the length.

Comment: @Hassan Imam how to do this sir?

Comment: Change `$scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList       = [];` to `$scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList       = {};` Alternatively, you can use `$scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList.push(buyerKeyId +':'+ keyId);` instead of `$scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList[buyerKeyId] = keyId;` and then directly access the `length`

Comment: sir i am using this but got error:  angular.min.js:118 TypeError: $scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList.indexOf is not a function

Comment: Change code `if($scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList.indexOf(keyId)){` to `if($scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList[keyId]){`

Comment: sir again got error  " Cannot read property '4827130923843584' of undefined"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156887/discussion-between-hassan-imam-and-kapil-soni).

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate length directly as :

```
 $scope.totalSharedUserCount =$scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList.length ;
```

And

```
 $scope.totalSharedUserCount =$scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList.length;
```

Or you change your array , if you want to use your approach only :

```
$scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList = {};   

$scope.selectBuyerInAlbum = function(index, isChecked, keyId) {
if(isChecked) {
  if($scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList.keyId){
      var keyId = keyId;
      var buyerKeyId = keyId.toString();
      $scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList[buyerKeyId] = keyId;
      $scope.countBuyerInAlbum ++;

      $scope.totalSharedUserCount = 
      Object.keys($scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList).length;
    }
} 
}
```

Comment: sir check my udpated  code i  am using this code i will get this after using this code?

Comment: No you have written : Object.keys($scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList).length , Can you change it to : $scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList.length

Comment: Mam, check my updated code i am also using $scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList.length ?

Comment: i have updated my answer , tell me  if it works ! :)

Comment: Mam, i m using this  but got error: angular.min.js:118 TypeError: $scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList.indexOf is not a function

Comment: yes because now its not an array . you will have to change it like $scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList.keyId  instead of indexOf

Comment: Mam how to match the index without indexOf?

Comment: you dont need to match it , previously you were checking whether that key exist in array or not . Similarly here you will check that key exist in object ornot. If it exist then you will go inside if condition . Why do you want to match index . Its not an array anymore. you can access keys directly .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156899/discussion-between-kapil-soni-and-vertika).

Answer (score 0):

You can see the code like this:

```
$scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList       = []; 
$scope.countBuyerInAlbum          = 0;
$scope.totalSharedUserCount;
$scope.selectBuyerInAlbum = function(index, isChecked, keyId) {
if(isChecked) {
  if($scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList.indexOf(keyId)){
      var keyId = keyId;
      $scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList.push(keyId);
      $scope.countBuyerInAlbum ++;

      $scope.totalSharedUserCount = $scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList.length;
    }
} else {
    var index  = keyId;
    delete $scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList[index];
    $scope.countBuyerInAlbum --;
    $scope.totalSharedUserCount = $scope.sharedBuyerKeyIdList.length;
  }
}
```